# Disable onClick for next button when overlayed btn is pressed

Tags: android

- I have two buttons on action bar `btn1` & `btn2`.
- They are positioned on RHS of action bar (***same location***)
- **btn2** is initially disabled `(visibility = GONE)` and ONLY **btn1** is `visible`
- I click **btn1** and set `btn1.visibility = GONE` and `btn2.visibilty = VISIBLE`
- However, even if I clicked only ***btn1***, ***`btn2.onClick`*** is also getting executed.

What needs to be done to ***prevent*** `btn2.onClick` to be executed when ***btn1*** is clicked??

Comment: **Please** provide the code where you set click listeners, your layout, etc... Also...this reads awfully wrong. Are you using an option menu? And if not, why not?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Its unrelated but do you mind telling why its awfully wrong. I do not use options menu. I have a custom action bar with minimal btns displayed at any given point. Is it mandatory to use options menu? Options menu forces my user 1 more click.

Comment: Sorry. This is just my opinion. I've seen my fair share of custom implementations to know that they are often bugged and don't work properly, like they say, don't reinvent the wheel. Why would it require another click? using `app:showAsAction="always"` there is no overflow menu, the buttons just get displayed in the menu bar as I'm guessing they are with your implementation

Comment: Thank you..if its not mandatory then I am fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
//After the initialization of the buttons
btn2.setEnabled(false);
//In btn1's onClick() 
btn2.setEnabled(true);btn1.setEnabled(false);
//In btn2's onClick() 
btn2.setEnabled(false);btn1.setEnabled(true);
```